# Getting text of checked radio button

Tags: javascript, html

how to get text instead of value, when I click on the radio button?

Below code gets Value of the radio button. I want to take texts (Shows or Movies). Thanks in advance.

```js
function myFunction(contentType) {
  document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML = contentType;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" oninput="myFunction(this.value)" value="1" name="contentType"><span>Shows</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" oninput="myFunction(this.value)" value="2" name="contentType" ><span>Movies</span></label>

<span id="myspan" class="text-muted" ></span>
```

Comment: Why don't you use string as parameter of myFunction?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your **myFunction()** do this:

```
function myFunction(inputRadio) {
  document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML = inputRadio.nextSibling.innerText;
}
```

In your HTML change **this.value** to **this**, and you are good to go!

```
<label><input type="radio" oninput="myFunction(this)" value="1" name="contentType"><span>Shows</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" oninput="myFunction(this)" value="2" name="contentType" ><span>Movies</span></label>

<span id="myspan" class="text-muted" ></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to either add a data attribute to your radio button, or manually query the DOM to get the text content of the label related to that radio button.

```js
function myFunction(input) {
  document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML = input.dataset.textValue;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" oninput="myFunction(this)" value="1" data-text-value="Shows" name="contentType"><span>Shows</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" oninput="myFunction(this)" value="2" data-text-value="Movies" name="contentType" ><span>Movies</span></label>

<span id="myspan" class="text-muted" ></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(contentType) {
    document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML = contentType;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" oninput="myFunction(this.value)" value="shows" name="contentType"><span>Shows</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" oninput="myFunction(this.value)" value="movies" name="contentType" ><span>Movies</span></label>
  
<span id="myspan" class="text-muted" ></span>
```